# Is 风光不再 correct in 广州恒大风光不再?

Tags: idioms

I think it is a misspelling, which should have been 风光不在.
不再 is no more, or not any more
不在 is absent, unavailable
Comparing the two, I think only the latter makes sense, for the former there has to be another complementary words, such as 广州恒大不再（经营足球业务）

Answer (score 4):

It is correct. 风光不再 is an idiom, meaning the previous upwards trends (of something) is no more, and it is on the decline.

In this sentence, it means that the soccer club is not doing well in recent years, comparing to its peak (winning 2 Asian championships). It is on the decline.

Answer (score 2):

1]

在 is a complementation which negative form is 不在.

提问:

- 小王在吗? (is Wang here?)

回答:

- 小王在. (Yes, Wang is here.)
- 小王不在. (No, Wang is not here.)

2]

再 is a adverb which negative form is 不再.

- 他再次进球. (He do the goal again.)
- 他不再进球. (He were to do not goal again.)

We use 再次 instead of 再 to indicate something have happened just like above, or use 再 to indicate states of unreality, for example:

- 你再进球, 我就揍你. (I'll kick you if you goal again.)

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

不在 - 指不位于或处于某处 (be not in; be out) - 他不在 (He's out/He's not in)

不再 - 结束;停止;终止 (no more; no longer) - 风光不再 (flourishing scene no more - indicating "the past honor and glory has ended")

Answer (score 0):

That's fine. "不再" means "not any more" here.

And "风光" literally translate to great view. Imply for been in great position or in great power, and therefore been worshiped or been admired.

So, "风光不再" means: been worshiped no more.

But to be honestly, I think "不在" may also work, only it doesn't emphasize the emotionally taking pity on the fact. If using "风光不在", simply specify the fact of losing the position. For "风光不再", it feels like: One been worshiped no more, what a pity...

Anyway, like I always say: Chinese seems to become a stream of consciousness or even subconsciousness now days.